# Ошибка сборки boost. ERROR: b2/4.10.1: Error in source() method, line 75

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, boost, build-error, conan

Всем привет. Ошибка при сборке boost внутри контейнера:

**ERROR: b2/4.10.1: Error in source() method, line 75 b2/4.10.1: Configuring sources in /root/.conan/data/b2/4.10.1/*/*/source/src Downloading b2-4.10.1.tar.bz2 completed [769.01k] b2/4.10.1: b2/4.10.1: ERROR: b2/4.10.1: Error in source() method, line 75 get(self, self.conan_data["sources"][self.version], strip_root=True) ReadError: file could not be opened successfully**

**Conanfile**

```
[requires]
boost/1.80.0
utfcpp/4.0.1

[options]
boost:header_only=False
boost:without_stacktrace=True

[generators]
cmake
virtualenv
cmake_find_package
```

**Conan profile:**

```
[settings]
os=Linux
os.distro=CentOS7
arch=x86
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=9.4
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

docker собирается on centos7x32, gcc9.4.0 compiler
сам conan - 1.61.0
комадна запуска:

```
conan install -pr:b linux_x86_build -pr:h linux_x86_build -if build /home/project/scanner/ --build=missing
```

Что не так, не пойму

Comment: `file could not be opened successfully` нет прав? диск забился?

Comment: Возможно забился, хотя странно, права не нужны, в контейнеры всё так пролетает. Решилось само собой